# Python string encode not working for rest api headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am sending a blob string in the rest API headers as a token.

[image]

Which I want to access and covert it into btyes

```
bob = request.META.get('HTTP_BLOB_TOKEN')
bob_encoded = bob.encode()
```

**String raw blob**

```
\x01\x02\x02\x00xM\xc3\xa3\xc2\x98\xc2\xac\xc3\xb7\xc3\x87\xc2\xaf\x7f\xc2\x95q\xc3\x85R\xc3\x8ae\xc3\x80\xc2\xa9\xc3\x90\xc3\x85\xc2\xa9\x15\xc3\x82=\xc2\xa0N\xc2\x88\xc3\xaf#5x=\x01%\x0e\xc2\xa8aT\xc3\x8a\xc3\x81\xc3\x92"\xc2\xa0\x04N$GF\x00\x00\x00h0f\x06\t\xc2\x86H\xc2\x86\xc3\xb7\r\x01\x07\x06\xc2\xa0Y0W\x02\x01\x000R\x06\t*\xc2\x86H\xc2\x86\xc3\xb7\r\x01\x07\x010\x1e\x06\t`\xc2\x86H\x01e\x03\x04\x01.0\x11\x04\x0c\xc2\x9e\x12\xc3\x82\xc2\x8bi\xc2\xb7\xc3\x93+\x18\xc3\xbfs\xc2\x97\x02\x01\x10\xc2\x80%p\xc2\xb3\xc2\x9b\x03%X\xc3\x8a\xc2\xad\xc3\xb1Cbi=w\xc3\xa9\xc3\x9f\xc2\xb0\x18nK7\xc2\x9a\xc3\x90\xc3\x9e\xc3\xb3HB\xc3\xbd\xc3\x94\x07\xc3\xba\xc3\x83\x1c\xc3\x8f\xc3\x96\x0e2*
```

**Expected blob in byte**

```
b'\x01\x02\x02\x00xM\xc3\xa3\xc2\x98\xc2\xac\xc3\xb7\xc3\x87\xc2\xaf\x7f\xc2\x95q\xc3\x85R\xc3\x8ae\xc3\x80\xc2\xa9\xc3\x90\xc3\x85\xc2\xa9\x15\xc3\x82=\xc2\xa0N\xc2\x88\xc3\xaf#5x=\x01%\x0e\xc2\xa8aT\xc3\x8a\xc3\x81\xc3\x92"\xc2\xa0\x04N$GF\x00\x00\x00h0f\x06\t\xc2\x86H\xc2\x86\xc3\xb7\r\x01\x07\x06\xc2\xa0Y0W\x02\x01\x000R\x06\t*\xc2\x86H\xc2\x86\xc3\xb7\r\x01\x07\x010\x1e\x06\t`\xc2\x86H\x01e\x03\x04\x01.0\x11\x04\x0c\xc2\x9e\x12\xc3\x82\xc2\x8bi\xc2\xb7\xc3\x93+\x18\xc3\xbfs\xc2\x97\x02\x01\x10\xc2\x80%p\xc2\xb3\xc2\x9b\x03%X\xc3\x8a\xc2\xad\xc3\xb1Cbi=w\xc3\xa9\xc3\x9f\xc2\xb0\x18nK7\xc2\x9a\xc3\x90\xc3\x9e\xc3\xb3HB\xc3\xbd\xc3\x94\x07\xc3\xba\xc3\x83\x1c\xc3\x8f\xc3\x96\x0e2'
```

**Current output**

```
b'\\\x01\\\x02\\\x02\\\x00xM\\\xc3\\\xa3\\\xc2\\\x98\\\xc2\\\xac\\\xc3\\\xb7\\\xc3\\\x87\\\xc2\\\xaf\\\x7f\\\xc2\\\x95q\\xc3\\x85R\\xc3\\x8ae\\xc3\\x80\\\xc2\\xa9\\xc3\\x90\\xc3\\x85\\\xc2\\xa9\\x15\\xc3\\x82=\\xc2\\xa0N\\\xc2\\x88\\xc3\\xaf#5x=\\x01%\\\x0e\\xc2\\xa8aT\\xc3\\x8a\\xc3\\x81\\\xc3\\x92"\\xc2\\xa0\\x04N$GF\\\x00\\x00\\x00h0f\\x06\\t\\xc2\\x86H\\\xc2\\x86\\xc3\\xb7\\r\\x01\\x07\\\x06\\xc2\\xa0Y0W\\x02\\x01\\x000R\\\x06\\t*\\xc2\\x86H\\xc2\\x86\\xc3\\\xb7\\r\\x01\\x07\\x010\\x1e\\x06\\t`\\xc2\\x86H\\x01e\\x03\\x04\\x01.0\\x11\\x04\\x0c\\xc2\\x9e\\x12\\\xc3\\x82\\xc2\\x8bi\\xc2\\xb7\\\xc3\\\x93+\\\x18\\\xc3\\\xbfs\\\xc2\\\x97\\\x02\\\x01\\\x10\\\xc2\\\x80%p\\\xc2\\\xb3\\\xc2\\\x9b\\\x03%X\\\xc3\\\x8a\\\xc2\\\xad\\\xc3\\\xb1Cbi=w\\\xc3\\\xa9\\\xc3\\\x9f\\\xc2\\\xb0\\\x18nK7\\\xc2\\\x9a\\\xc3\\\x90\\\xc3\\\x9e\\\xc3\\\xb3HB\\\xc3\\\xbd\\\xc3\\\x94\\\x07\\\xc3\\\xba\\\xc3\\\x83\\\x1c\\\xc3\\\x8f\\\xc3\\\x96\\\x0e2'
```

Comment: What is the difference between 'Expected blob in byte' and 'Current output'?

Comment: @Corralien updated. Please check

Comment: The string raw blob is the output of `print(bob)`. What is the output of `print(repr(bob))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending a blob string, you're sending just a string which starts with `\x01`. It literally contains chars `\`, `x`, `0`, `1`, and not a single `'\x01'` symbol. Compare:

```
In [6]: "\x01".encode()
Out[6]: b'\x01'

In [7]: r"\x01".encode()
Out[7]: b'\\x01'
```

Instead of sending blob in this format you can encode it firstly with base64 (or any other ascii encoding):

```
In [16]: s = '\x01\x02\x02\x00xM\xc3\xa3\xc2\x98\xc2\xac\xc3\xb7\xc3\x87\xc2\xaf\x7f\xc2\x95q\xc3\x85R\xc3\x8ae\xc3\x80\xc2\xa9\xc3\x90\xc3\x85\xc2\xa9\x15\xc3
    ...: \x82=\xc2\xa0N\xc2\x88\xc3\xaf#5x=\x01%\x0e\xc2\xa8aT\xc3\x8a\xc3\x81\xc3\x92"\xc2\xa0\x04N$GF\x00\x00\x00h0f\x06\t\xc2\x86H\xc2\x86\xc3\xb7\r\x01\x07
    ...: \x06\xc2\xa0Y0W\x02\x01\x000R\x06\t\xc2\x86H\xc2\x86\xc3\xb7\r\x01\x07\x010\x1e\x06\t`\xc2\x86H\x01e\x03\x04\x01.0\x11\x04\x0c\xc2\x9e\x12\xc3\x82\xc2
    ...: \x8bi\xc2\xb7\xc3\x93+\x18\xc3\xbfs\xc2\x97\x02\x01\x10\xc2\x80%p\xc2\xb3\xc2\x9b\x03%X\xc3\x8a\xc2\xad\xc3\xb1Cbi=w\xc3\xa9\xc3\x9f\xc2\xb0\x18nK7\xc
    ...: 2\x9a\xc3\x90\xc3\x9e\xc3\xb3HB\xc3\xbd\xc3\x94\x07\xc3\xba\xc3\x83\x1c\xc3\x8f\xc3\x96\x0e2*'

In [17]: payload = base64.b64encode(s.encode()).decode()

In [18]: payload
Out[18]: 'AQICAHhNw4PCo8OCwpjDgsKsw4PCt8ODwofDgsKvf8OCwpVxw4PChVLDg8KKZcODwoDDgsKpw4PCkMODwoXDgsKpFcODwoI9w4LCoE7DgsKIw4PCryM1eD0BJQ7DgsKoYVTDg8KKw4PCgcODwpIiw4LCoAROJEdGAAAAaDBmBgnDgsKGSMOCwobDg8K3DQEHBsOCwqBZMFcCAQAwUgYJw4LChkjDgsKGw4PCtw0BBwEwHgYJYMOCwoZIAWUDBAEuMBEEDMOCwp4Sw4PCgsOCwotpw4LCt8ODwpMrGMODwr9zw4LClwIBEMOCwoAlcMOCwrPDgsKbAyVYw4PCisOCwq3Dg8KxQ2JpPXfDg8Kpw4PCn8OCwrAYbks3w4LCmsODwpDDg8Kew4PCs0hCw4PCvcODwpQHw4PCusODwoMcw4PCj8ODwpYOMio='

In [19]: base64.b64decode(payload.encode()).decode()
Out[19]: '\x01\x02\x02\x00xMÃ£Â\x98Â¬Ã·Ã\x87Â¯\x7fÂ\x95qÃ\x85RÃ\x8aeÃ\x80Â©Ã\x90Ã\x85Â©\x15Ã\x82=Â\xa0NÂ\x88Ã¯#5x=\x01%\x0eÂ¨aTÃ\x8aÃ\x81Ã\x92"Â\xa0\x04N$GF\x00\x00\x00h0f\x06\tÂ\x86HÂ\x86Ã·\r\x01\x07\x06Â\xa0Y0W\x02\x01\x000R\x06\tÂ\x86HÂ\x86Ã·\r\x01\x07\x010\x1e\x06\t`Â\x86H\x01e\x03\x04\x01.0\x11\x04\x0cÂ\x9e\x12Ã\x82Â\x8biÂ·Ã\x93+\x18Ã¿sÂ\x97\x02\x01\x10Â\x80%pÂ³Â\x9b\x03%XÃ\x8aÂ\xadÃ±Cbi=wÃ©Ã\x9fÂ°\x18nK7Â\x9aÃ\x90Ã\x9eÃ³HBÃ½Ã\x94\x07ÃºÃ\x83\x1cÃ\x8fÃ\x96\x0e2*'

In [20]: base64.b64decode(payload.encode()).decode() == s
Out[20]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you have to specify an encoding:

```
bob_encoded = bob.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Still the same.